# tab completion for identifiers

Tags: command-line, bash

Very often, I need to use an identifier for a command. For example,

`ssh server1-name`

Obviously if I were to hit `[tab]` while typing `server1` the `-name` part of the string identifier would not complete. Is there a way in bash to get that to work?

It clearly works for other identifiers like directory names. i.e.

`cd /var/www/ht[tab]` will result in `cd /var/www/html` is there a reason it doesn't work for things like ssh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entries in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` are hashed and therefore can't be read by `bash-completion`, see [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/42382) and [a similar question on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136351/autocomplete-server-names-for-ssh-and-scp).

As a workaround there is [this script](https://gist.github.com/jordandcarter/730955) (also see [here](https://gist.github.com/aliang/1024466) for comments) for `~/.profile`:

```
_complete_ssh_hosts ()
{
        COMPREPLY=()
        cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
        comp_ssh_hosts=`cat ~/.ssh/known_hosts | \
                        cut -f 1 -d ' ' | \
                        sed -e s/,.*//g | \
                        grep -v ^# | \
                        uniq | \
                        grep -v "\[" ;
                cat ~/.ssh/config | \
                        grep "^Host " | \
                        awk '{print $2}'
                `
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${comp_ssh_hosts}" -- $cur))
        return 0
}
complete -F _complete_ssh_hosts ssh
```

Another attempt to work around this issue can be found [in this answer on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/181603/246819):

```
_ssh() 
{
    local cur prev opts
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
    opts=$(grep '^Host' ~/.ssh/config ~/.ssh/config.d/* | grep -v '[?*]' | cut -d ' ' -f 2-)
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$opts" -- ${cur}) )
    return 0
}
complete -F _ssh ssh
```

Unfortunately I'm not able to test it right now, but you may just try them both. The second one looks much simpler to me, I'd expect it to run faster.

Comment: Thanks that second shell script looks a lot more concise and with very minor customization I was able to get it working. Might be do a good idea to modify the script to check if `~/.ssh/config` or `~/.ssh/config.d` exists first.